# Prometheus/Thanos -> Can we add store specific TLS in Thanos querier stores? Essentially having http and https in the same store array

Tags: prometheus, thanos

Issue:

I added two store endpoints. One is http and another is https. For the https, I added the grpc tls configs, and i am able to authenticate and view the stores in thanos, but for the http. It fails to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two queriers (one TLS another without) then on top of these you can use another querier to query from these.

Queriers can be stacked on top of one another. It seems the   that the TLS config is for all or none.